# How to create spreadsheet in node js?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

Hello I created a new GCP project and have a service account json.

I want to create a new spreadsheet and I have google api sheets turned on.

Is it easier to use google-spreadsheet npm package or use examples from Google docs?

I tried ts-node this but it gets killed

```
import {google} from 'googleapis';
const sheets = google.sheets('v4');

async function main() {
  const authClient = await authorize();
  const request = {
    resource: {
      "spreadsheetId": "test-1234"
    },

    auth: authClient,
  };

  try {
    const response = (await sheets.spreadsheets.create(request)).data;
    // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
main();

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: './credentials.json',
  scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
})

async function authorize() {
  // TODO: Change placeholder below to generate authentication credentials. See
  // https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/nodejs#step_3_set_up_the_sample
  //
  // Authorize using one of the following scopes:
  //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
  //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
  //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
  let authClient = await auth.getClient();

  if (authClient == null) {
    throw Error('authentication failed');
  }

  return authClient;
}
```

Comment: Did your auth succeed? see google sheet api for nodejs, https://www.section.io/engineering-education/google-sheets-api-in-nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution to authorize the Google Sheets API, is to follow these steps:

- Copy and paste the contents of the [NodeJS quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) page and make the following changes:

  - Change the `SCOPES` to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`
  - Modify all references to `listMajors` to `createSheet`
- Append this function to the file:

```js
async function createSheet(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth });
  try {
    console.log(await sheets.spreadsheets.create());
  } catch (error) {
    console.err("Unhandled error");
  }
}
```

- Run the `node quickstart.js`

---

###### Documentation:

- [`Sheets.create`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create)